# Magento 2.3 - Get all values from custom multiselect attribute

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.0

On the product page (within the "column main" area) I have created a phtml file. In this I want to echo all the chosen options of a custom multiselect attribute.

What I have:

1. current product (via
   `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()`)
2. name of my custom attribute (xyz)
3. for example 3 selected options out of 5 (e.g. "red", "green" and "black")

What I need:

- The three values of the selected options

I tried

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?>
<?php $currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product'); //get current product ?>
<?php echo $currentProduct->getCustomAttribute('xyz')->getValue(); ?>
<?php echo $currentProduct->getAttributeText('xyz'); ?>
```

But there is no output.

I found a lot of possible solutions using `->getResource()` but I have come to learn this method is deprecated as from 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, it was a cache problem...

Might be useful for others:

```
<?php echo $currentProduct->getCustomAttribute('xyz')->getValue(); ?>
```

delivers the IDs of all multiselect options (e.g. "13,15,16")

```
<?php echo $currentProduct->getAttributeText('xyz'); ?>
```

returns an array with all the values needed ( `Array ( [0] => Green [1] => Red [2] => Black` - use `print_r` to get this).